# Wrong number of arguments for model new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am really confused as to why this is happening. I'm calling the 'create' method via ajax and it returns a 500 error. This is the controller:

```
class CallbacksController < ApplicationController
  def create
    new_callback = Callback.new({
      date: DateTime.now,
      status: 'Open',
      notes: params[:callbackNotes],
      action: "#{params[:callbackDate]}:#{params[:callbackTime]}",
      admin: current_user.name,
      set_by: current_user.name
    })

    customer = Customer.find params[:customer_id]

    if customer.exists?
      new_callback.customer = customer
      new_callback.save

      render json: {success: true}
    end
  end
end
```

I get the error:

`wrong number of arguments (1 for 5)` highlighting the line `new_callback = ...`

I've tried it with both `new_callback = Callback.new({date: DateTime.now})` and `new_callback = Callback.new`. Both return similar errors. I thought it was to do with the model but the full trace says not:

`app/controllers/callbacks_controller.rb:3:in 'new'`
`app/controllers/callbacks_controller.rb:3:in 'create'`

The exact same line works perfect in the console however?

Comment: Please show us your callback class

Comment: According to the error, Your CallBack class initializer is expecting 5 arguments

Comment: What does `Callback.superclass` return in your controller binding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the Callback is a rails class inside the ActiveSupport package, ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback. and the constructor for it is like this new(chain, filter, kind, options, klass). Rename you model name will solve it.

Comment: How weird. I haven't had any problems with it up until this point. Cheers!